# pd.read_csv,ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

In Python, when I run this code:

```
def parse_japanese_date(s):
    base_years={'S':1925,'H':1988}
    era=s[0]
    year,month,day=s[1:].split('.')
    year=base_years[era]+int(year)
    return datetime(year,int(month),int(day))

df_jgbcm=pd.read_csv('jgbcm_all.csv',encoding='cp932',index_col=0,parse_dates=True, date_parser=parse_japanese_date,na_values=['-'])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

What does that error mean?
What should I do to modify this?

Comment: Include the full error traceback. May be this: `year,month,day=s[1:].split('.')`. Try to print `s[1:].split('.')` and see if the list has 3 values. Perhaps create a [mcve] to get better solutions.

Comment: could you post some sample data, how you're doing it can probably be done more efficiciently

Answer (score 0):

What's the full traceback?  I don't think this is an error relating to pandas, but rather an error relating to this line in your function:

```
year,month,day=s[1:].split('.')
```

More than likely, your csv file isn't giving you enough information to assign `year,month,day` values, and this error reflects this.

Answer (score 0):

Unpacking is where you have some comma separated variable names on the left and some interable on the right like a list or tuple it then separates the values in that iterable into the comma separated variables you set.

```
year,month,day=s[1:].split('.')
```

I imagine this is the line throwing the error. It may be that there are more or less values in the iterable than the number of variables you have set. So you might need to add or remove one. If you need to add one It's common to use an underscore for variables you are unpacking but don't care about e.g

```
year,month,day,_=s[1:].split('.')
```

I think your error

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

is saying that the variable you are splitting is returning less data than you need. so you might want to check what it contains before you unpack by printing or debugging the contents of it